# Keras Custom Scaling Layer

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

For my work, I need to make a layer, that has only single weight, that will multiply the data in the current layer by some trained value. Is there a way to do this?

Or change the merge layer, which will be able to make a weighted average of input layers.
Thanks

Comment: Have you taken a look at Keras lambda layers, they can do what you want easily.

Comment: unfortunately, they have only fixed multiplier(as I know) and cannot store any parameters in them

Answer (score 4):

Extending @user375348's answer you can create a learned variable and use it within the `Lambda`:

```
initial_value = 1
learned = tf.Variable(initial_value, name='learned_scalar')
Lambda(lambda x: x * learned)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try Lambda layer

```
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: x *MyValue))
```

https://keras.io/layers/core/#lambda

Comment: MyValue won't be trained in your way, I need to make it adaptive

Comment: What function does your Merge layer apply?

Comment: where the * means simply scaling

Comment: Not sure this is useful, because the weights applied to input2 will already be trained in the layer after Merge

Comment: That's a thing.  I have already trained weights for different inputs, I just need to adjust the merge weights